# Temple for Tri murthis and its significance

Tags: vishnu, shiva, brahma

Where is the temple for Trimurthis   Brahma,  Vishnu and Siva with their consorts and what is the significance of the same?

Answer (score 2):

> This is a temple from where all the three Lords – Brahma, Vishnu and Shiva grace the devotees. It is in **Trichy,  Tamilnadu**.
>
> The place is known as Pichandarkovil as Lord Shiva was relieved of His doshas here.  As Lord Vishnu stood here as Kadhamba tree, it is also known as Kadhambanur-Karambanur.  Husband and wife should live in unity understanding each other, a life described Uthamba meaning best, hence, the place is also known as Uthamarkoil.  As all the three Lords grace here with their respective consorts, Tirumangai Azhwar had praised this temple in His Mangalasasanam as Uthamar koil.  It is believed that families will prosper with prayers in this temple.

Image: http://img1.dinamalar.com/KovilImages/GalleryLarge/T_1024_169.jpg

For more information:*
Link: http://temple.dinamalar.com/en/new_en.php?id=169

Dinamalar is a Tamil newsdaily. Hence the article will be in Tamil. The answer is given in brief in the second para.